# understandng the concept of information content

Tags: information-theory

I don't study computer science but I am interested in understanding the concept  of information content.

I saw these two example sentences:

```
a) On July 5th, it was over 100°F
b) On July 5th, it was 98°F
```

It said that sentence b) has a higher information content because for sentence a) there is only the possibility less than/more than and for sentence b) the is an infinite number of possibilities.

I would a agree that b) has a higher information content, but I don't understand the explanation.

I would say b) has a higher information content, because it tells you exactly what temperature there was.

But I guess my intuitive understanding is incorrect. I would say a message has a high information content if it leaves no room for interpretation.

```
a) Tomorrow, someone will visit me.
b) Tomorrow, my aunt will visit me.
```

I'd spontaneously say, b) is more informative, because it tells you exactly who is coming to visit. Is this correct here?

Form my non-scientific understanding, high information content would be good, because it leaves you without questions. But I guess in information theory, high information content is bad because it means the message needs a lot of bits for encoding and information is not seen as something good but just as something that needs to be transmitted. Is that a good way to put it?

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct: the number of additional binary questions you need to ask on average to nail down the details is essentially the information content.

However, there's no inherent *good* or *bad* in information theory unless you have an objective.

If you're objective is compress signal, information theory says the achievable limit is given by the information content. So in that sense, low information content signal is more compressible (this could be good if that's what you are looking for.)

For a communication channel, you want to maximize your usage of the channel capacity. If you are not using the channel to its max capacity, the information content wouldn't be as high as it could be.

For error correcting, you want to have redundancy which has same information content but larger bit representation. Smallest information content per symbol would mean no error correcting, so that's bad.